# Put only the stdout of the last shell command in a Python variable

Tags: python-3.x, bash

prova.sh contains:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Output that I don't want."
echo "Output that I don't want."
echo "Output that I don't want."
echo -e "Output that I want.\nI want this too.\
\nI want this too." #This is the last command of the bash script, which is what I'm looking for.
```

This solution:

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output('./prova.sh', shell=True, text=True)
print(output, end='')
```

puts the stdout of all shell commands in a variable:

```
Output that I don't want.
Output that I don't want.
Output that I don't want.
Output that I want.
I want this too.
I want this too.
```

but I just want the stdout of the last shell command:

```
Output that I want.
I want this too.
I want this too.
```

How can I get this?

Python 3.8.5

Existing questions only address how to get N lines or similar. In contrast, I only want the output of last command.

Comment: What do you consider "the last stdout"? The last *line*, or the last *batch* written to stdout?

Comment: For a shell subprocess you can just do "./prova.sh | tail -n 1" and you do not have to worry about it. The examples provided by @MisterMiyagi are great if the output is not large. If you need to do it in python. For a large input I would suggest to maybe use directly subprocess.run pipes witha ring buffer.

Comment: "What do you consider "the last stdout"? The last line, or the last batch written to stdout?" Regarding this question, I have also changed the title of my question to be clearer.

Comment: In general, you veritably cannot. What you are asking for is not well-defined – the ``stdin``/``stdout``/``stderr`` are *byte streams*, their payload has no discernible connection to how it was produced. You can react to *content* (e.g. newlines to get "the last n lines") but not to the source.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is one thing to want the last N lines, quite another to take the output of the last command, which can also be composed of multiple lines.

Comment: @DedicheAnonime I have voted to re-open the issue. As stated earlier, this is pretty much all you can do, though – either you take all output (as the current answer suggests) or you take n lines/characters/bytes/... of output. There is simply no such thing as "the output of the last command" in a stream.

Comment: I'm rather hesitant to vote to reopen; we no longer have "does not demonstrate a basic understanding" as a close reason but is this really going to help future visitors?

Comment: @tripleee Apparently 6 people thought the question has merit. It might be worth just answering with "not possible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away the output of previous commands in Bash script, coz it's impossible to identify which command is which command on Python side.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Output that I don't want." >/dev/null
echo "Output that I don't want." >/dev/null
echo "Output that I don't want." >/dev/null
echo -e "Output that I want.\nI want this too.\nI want this too." #This is the last command of the bash script, which is what I'm looking for.
```

Another solution is writing the output of last command to file:

```py
# Modify the Bash script
import io, re
with io.open("prova.sh","r") as f:
    script  = f.read().strip()
    script  = re.sub(r"#.*$","",script).strip() # Remove comment
    script += "\x20>out.txt"                    # Add output file

with io.open("prova.sh","w") as f:
    f.write(script)

# Execute it
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("./prova.sh", shell=True)
# print(output.decode("utf-8"))

# Get output
with io.open("out.txt","r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: This is just an example, the bash script is very complex, I wanted to avoid this redirect to null, which is the first thing I thought about.

Comment: i've added some work-around

Comment: You don't have to append `> /dev/null` to every command. Instead, wrap everything (except the last command) inside a single group; `{ ...; } > /dev/null`.

Comment: Is a good solution. With the future development of the file I will have to understand if it suits me.

Comment: Having become aware that a real solution to my problem does not yet exist, I believe that your solution, written inside a comment, is the one that comes closest. For this I vote you as the best answer.